# Как разделить два числа? Java

Tags: java

Например, пользователь вводит два целых числа в одну строку (8 13). Мне нужно разделить эти два числа и записать каждое из них в отдельную переменную. Как можно это сделать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно конкретно две переменных:

```
String[] stringifiedNumbers = str.split(" ");
int num, num2;
try {
    num = Integer.parseInt(stringifiedNumbers[0]);
    num2 = Integer.parseInt(stringifiedNumbers[1]);
} catch(Exception ignored) {
    System.out.println(stringifiedNumbers[0] + " или " + stringifiedNumbers[1] + " - не число");
}
```

Если чисел будет больше и необходимо найти их сумму/минимальное/максимальное:

```
int result = Arrays.stream(str.split(" "))
    .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
    .НеобходимаяФункция();
```

Answer (score 0):

Если между цифрами пробел то

```
str.split(" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот, накидал вам минимальный пример

```
 String input = "8 13";
String [] numbers = input.split(" ");
int num1 = Integer.parseInt(numbers[0]);
int num2 = Integer.parseInt(numbers[1]);
```